# cmake + VS = "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.References.UnresolvedBuildDependencyProjectReference"

Tags: c++, cmake, reference, c++20, visual-studio-2022

I have a very simple CMake solution with one shared library and one executable.

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)

project(Test)

add_subdirectory(A)
add_subdirectory(B)
```

A/CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

project(A)

file(GLOB_RECURSE Hdr CONFIGURE_DEPENDS inc/*)
file(GLOB_RECURSE Src CONFIGURE_DEPENDS src/*)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED ${Hdr} ${Src})
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} BEFORE PUBLIC inc PRIVATE src)

set_property(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} APPEND PROPERTY PUBLIC_HEADER ${Hdr})
```

A/CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

project(B)

file(GLOB_RECURSE Src CONFIGURE_DEPENDS src/*)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${Hdr} ${Src})
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} BEFORE PUBLIC inc PRIVATE src)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE A)
```

I use all these to generate a VS2022 solution and open it:

```
cmake.exe -S . -B tmp
start tmp\Test.sln
```

The CMake target "A" seems to be taken into consideration because I see the public headers folder (A/inc) amongst "Additional Include Directories" of VS project "B".
When I navigate in VS to B/References I see a reference to project "A" as expected:

[image: VisualStudio. Project References]

but when I double-click it or try to see its properties , I get:
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.References.UnresolvedBuildDependencyProjectReference"

[image: VisualStudio. Project Reference Error]

Is there a CMake+VS bug? or I do something wrong?

NOTE: if I create the entire solution by hand from Visual Studio (without CMake), it works fine!

Comment: That's weird. I have a project with multiple libs (although static) and everything works as expected in MSVS2022.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using **CMake 3.24.1** and **VS2019** and I'm facing the same problem. From what I see on my PC, I can conclude it's certainly not a CMake issue. That's because, after having used CMake to generate my VS Solution, I'm able to get rid of the problem by simply modifying the **vcxproj** file(s) inside my solution. However, there still is one thing I don't understand yet and what makes me to suspect VS having some kind of problem. Here is what I see/do.

My CMake generated solution contains one console application that depends on a number of static library projects: the projects are added to the application's **References** section. Now, when I double click on one of them I get the following message:

[image]

The Full Path property of the referenced project inside the Properties pane shows the same message.

To fix this I open the console application's vcxproj file and look for the following entry:

[image]

I remove the complete **ProjectReferences** element for each configuration, save the vcxproj file and restart my solution. In my case the problem is then solved: no more annoying message and the **Full path** property resolves to a valid path. But ...

Since I removed this ProjectReferences element the **Link Library Dependencies** property now defaults to **Yes**. I can verify this by opening the Property window and check the proper field. It shows **Yes**.

[image]

Now, I my case CMake generated a solution in which **LinkLibraryDependencies** was set to **false**. Therefore, I again open my console application's Property pane and set the **Link Library Dependencies** property back to **false**. I close the Property window and try rebuilding my project: no problem. Running the application:  no problem.

When, after updating the **Link Library Dependencies** property with **false** inside the Property pane, I save my project and then open the vcxproj file using a text editor, I notice the ProjectReferences element has been added again. It's set to **false**. That is as expected. But, when close and I re-open the solution *the initial problem is back again*. However, when I change the ProjectReferences property value from false to true inside the vcxproj file using a text editor, the problem stays away after opening the solution!!

Based on the experience with my VS Solution, I come to the following conclusion:

1. I can get rid of the problem by removing the complete ProjectReferences element from the vcxproj file (use text editor) and then re-open the solution. But then the **Link Library Dependencies** property defaults to Yes
2. I can then change the **Link Library Dependencies** property back and forth to Yes and No **without the problem shows up again**. (Note: what I find strange is that the vcxproj file is not updated when I modify some properties and close the Property window.
3. When the application's project is saved to disk (vcxproj file gets updated), re-opening the solution will bring back the problem but only in case the **Link Library Dependencies** property was saved as **false**.

Maybe I overlook something, but this looks as a VS problem to me. Not a showstopper but annoying it is.